# Install WiX service with custom parameters

Tags: wix

I am trying to install a win32-service that on start-up will read registry parameters from `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Service\MyService\Parameters`

I cant see any way in the `<ServiceInstall>` or `<ServiceConfig>` to specify some additional arbitrary registry parameters. Also I had the idea of adding it as a regular `<RegistryValue>`, but the `WriteRegistryValues`-action is scheduled before `InstallServices` so that seems like a bad move.

Is there some way to get WiX to write these?

Comment: Surely you want the data in the registry before InstallServices? Or perhaps more accurately before StartServices if the service is going to read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, this was a non-issue.
I believed that first adding registry info `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Service\MyService` and then installing the service would cause a fight between two actions accessing same registry. **Not an issue.**

Allowing action *WriteRegistryValues* to add things before *InstallServices* works just fine.